# missing return in global function expected to return 'Int'

Tags: swift

I want to define a function to return a sqrt of a number.
but Swift give me an error

```
func RenderNumber(_ number:Int) -> Int{
    for x in 1...number{
        if x*x == number{
            return x
        }
    }
}

print(RenderNumber(25))
```

Comment: If `x*x` never be equals to `number`, what's supposed it to be? That's what's asking the compiler. And compiler just compile, it doesn't interpret your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is fine, but you are not saying what if condition fails. There is no return if x*x!=number

So update function to below.

```
func RenderNumber(_ number:Int) -> Int{
    var returnValue : Int = 0
    for x in 1...number{
        if x*x == number{
            returnValue = x
            break
        }
    }
    return returnValue
}
```

So here it will return 0 if `x*x!=number`

Comment: An alternative is to return the input number itself or nil instead of 0.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson : That depends on what he want...

Comment: Of course, I just mentioned an alternative to consider for anyone reading this answer. Btw you should check the input value to avoid a runtime error.

Comment: let that developer do... we can't give each and everything to the developer...

Answer (score 3):

If a function has a return value you have to return something in any case.

If the square root of `number` is not an integer the condition `x*x == number` will never be `true`.

My suggestion is to return an optional and write the body of the function in a *swiftier* way

```
func renderNumber(_ number: Int) -> Int? {
    if number <= 0 { return nil }
    return (1...number).first{$0 * $0 == number}
}
```